# How to create loading script in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create loading script for my site. When the user clicks the button, it will call bunch functions and it takes time to load. I don't want the users to wait without loading gif. Are there any ways to solve this? Thanks a lot.

onload doesn't seem to work...

```
$('.test').click(function(){
  fun1();
  fun2();
  fun3();
  ....more
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just show the loading gif first and when everything is done hide it?

```
$('.test').click(function(){
  $("#LoadingGifId").show();
  fun1();
  fun2();
  fun3();
  ....more
  $("#LoadingGifId").hide();
});
```

If any of the functions are performing AJAX requests, you will want to hide the gif from the success callback function of the request you expect to finish last.

Comment: *Exactly* what I was just typing. Ok, my #Id was different.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to show a loading gif before the functions start and then hide it when they're finished.

```
$('.test').click(function(){

    $('.loadingGif').show();
    fun1();
    fun2();
    fun3();
    $('.loadingGif').hide();

});
```

This should work if none your functions are running asynchronously. If they are you'll probably need to use a callback function.